# SQL Server deleted identity columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

in SQL SERVER 2010, I deleted some columns that made use of identity fields.
I like to insert rows where the identity columns were deleted with the original values but not sure how to do so.

I tried edit but the identity columns were greyed out

```
    UPDATE table
```

Comment: There is no SQL Server version **2010** .... what are you using?? Also: **why** bother re-cycling those used identity values?? What do you get from doing that?? Seems like a lot of work for no benefit, really....

Comment: It is a very bad idea to reuse identity values.  YOu cannot ever rely on identies not to skip values (they are used even if you rollback the query for instance) so there is no reason at all to attempt to reuse them. If you have related tables without a defined PK/FK structure (you shouldn't but it happens) putting new data against those old numbers would relate the wrong records to them becasue those old records didn't get deleted along with the parent records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [YourTableName] ON
--do your update/insert query here
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [YourTableName] OFF
```

Comment: I think it is a mistake to say `SQL SERVER 2010`. This is a solution for his requirement and it works `SQL SERVER 2000` and later versions. [SET IDENTITY_INSERT - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: I'll give you back the +1 that someone took away from you, because you did answer the question on how to reuse identity values. However the points made above about the dangers in (and pointlessness of) doing so should not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why you care whether there are gaps in your identity columns? If you just want some pretty ID number next to a label (and aren't worried about related data in other tables, or whether the 2nd row retains the ID 2 even if ID 1 is deleted), you can always derive these meaningless ID numbers at runtime, e.g.

```
SELECT col, MeaninglessID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col)
FROM dbo.table
ORDER BY col;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to reseed the identity:

```
dbcc checkident (mytable, reseed, 30)
```

Comment: But that **potentially** causes duplicates, if values higher than e.g. 30 in your sample here exist! Be **very careful** with this operation!! Reseeding an IDENTITY to a given value does **NOT** skip existing values higher than the reseed value - a common misconception!

Comment: That's right, and why? Because an IDENTITY property does not enforce uniqueness on its own. I blogged about some similar misconceptions about IDENTITY columns here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/02/27/bad-habits-to-kick-believing-everything-you-hear-or-read.aspx